# Как стартовать функцию только один раз?

Tags: c#, функции

Ситуация очень простая. Мониторю изменение файла, через штатный `FileSystemWatcher`. Происходит изменение файла - запускается функция растартующая сервис. Проблема в том, что оно походу генерирует несколько событий (не знаю каких) и у меня на консоль выводится все, как будто файл менялся три раза.

Никак не могу сделать, чтобы нужная функция запускалась только один раз. Вроде бы все очень просто. Придумал `bool status = true`, но он что-то не дает то, что нужно.

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class FileMon
{
    public static bool status = false;

    public static void Run()
    {
        try
        {

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"D:\test\";
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine(status);
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }

    static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);
        status = true;
        Console.WriteLine(status);

        if (status == true)
        {
            RestartService();
            status = false;
        }

        else
        {

        }

    }

    public static void RestartService()
    {

        ServiceController service = new ServiceController("6to4");
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;

            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
            Console.WriteLine("trying to stop");

            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

        //     Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("stoping.........");

            // count the rest of the timeout
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000 - (millisec2 - millisec1));
        //    Console.ReadKey();

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        }
        catch
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Вот здесь переменная `status` всегда `true`:

        status = true;
        Console.WriteLine(status);

        if (status == true)

Comment: Оно мне по прежнему продолжает обрабатывать трижды. После запуска и изменения тестового файла пишет:
false
changed
false
changed
false
changed

Comment: Задампите ваши эвенты, например, таким путем: `Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType)` и выложите лог.

Comment: Пишет:
False

Changed

False

File: D:\test\1.txt Changed

Changed

False

File: D:\test\1.txt Changed

Changed

False

File: D:\test\1.txt Changed

Comment: В таком случае, либо вы действительно вызвали `Run` три раза в своем коде, либо в файле произошли три независимых изменения. Не уверен, что можно удаленно помочь в этой ситуации. Можете отследить действия над файловой системой чем-нибудь типа [`Process Monitor`.][1]

[1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Честно я думаю, что просто ошибка какая-то в коде. Не могли бы у себя скомпилировать все?

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю у вас файл D:\test\[1.txt](http://1.txt) обновляется так:

- read (изменение времени последнего доступа)
- delete
- write

Соответственно генерируется 3 события.
Думаю алгоритм должен быть такой:

- происходит изменение файла - запускается задача рестарта сервиса с таймаутом t
- происходит изменение файла в период ожидания рестарта сервиса - таймаут снова ставиться в t
- по истечении таймаута - происходит рестарт

Comment: Мне кажется, что изменение времени последнего доступа цеплялось бы, если был бы установлен `NotifyFilters.LastAccess.` По коду же ловятся только изменения, попадающие под `NotifyFilters.LastWrite`.

Comment: Извините, не обратил внимания на NotifyFilter, но это алгоритм не меняет. Еще добавил бы рестарт при превышении количества событий определенного значения не выходящих за таймаут.

Answer (score 2):

- Из этого [**треда:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449993/vb-net-filesystemwatcher-multiple-change-events)

> **Multiple Created Events Generated for a Single Action**
>
> You may notice in certain situations that a single creation event generates multiple Created events that are handled by your component. For example, if you use a `FileSystemWatcher` component to monitor the creation of new files in a directory, and then test it by using Notepad to create a file, you may see two `Created` events generated even though only a single file was created. This is because Notepad performs multiple file system actions during the writing process. Notepad writes to the disk in batches that create the content of the file and then the file attributes. Other applications may perform in the same manner. Because `FileSystemWatcher` monitors the operating system activities, all events that these applications fire will be picked up.
>
> Note: Notepad may also cause other interesting event generations. For example, if you use the `ChangeEventFilter` to specify that you want to watch only for attribute changes, and then you write to a file in the directory you are watching using Notepad, you will raise an event. This is because Notepad updates the `Archived` attribute for the file during this operation.

- В общем, мысль следующая - в вашем коде, который использует `FileSystemWatcher`, некорректно делать предположение о том, что `event` эквивалентен изменению файла в привычном смысле этого слова.

> Никто не мешает коду других приложения совершать `batch`-операции записи и на каждый атомарный `write` в таком случае будет генерироваться по эвенту.

- Я бы на вашем месте каким-либо образом *модифицировал логику* рестарта сервиса - либо задал бы какой-нибудь минимальный период для возможности его рестарта, либо попробовал бы переделать систему так, чтобы она не требовала перезагрузки.

> Представьте себе, например, что есть некоторый логгер, который 10 раз в секунду обновляет файл, а вы цепляетесь на `Changed` для этого файла. **Вы хотите 10 раз в секунду перезапускать ваш сервис?**